# Markers in leaflet map using tabletop.js Why its not working?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, tabletop.js

I'm noob to javascript... I tried to find a solution to a problem on a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55663520/how-to-add-markers-to-leaflet-map-with-tabletop-js), but I don't know why it doesn't work in my case. I can't comment there so I add new question.

All my code is here: [Link to Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yozz84/nvpeoqf1/9/)

When I changed code with example, the map stopped showing.
Where have I done the mistake? Thank You for helping me.

Main part of js is like this:

```
function myFunction() {

// Add MAP
var map = L.map('map').setView([54.151, 17.823], 9);
var basemap = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    minZoom: 5,
    maxZoom: 19
});
basemap.addTo(map);

/* ----------------------------------------------- */
// ZOOMING TO DETECT LOCATION
// map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});
/* ----------------------------------------------- */
// INFO ABOUT DETECT LOCATION      
function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy;

    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
        .bindPopup("Jesteśw odległości " + radius + " [m] od tego punktu.").openPopup();

    L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
}

map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);

// ERROR DETECT LOCATION
function onLocationError(e) {
    alert(e.message);
}

// MOUSE CLICK POSITION
var popup = L.popup();

function onMapClick(e) {
    popup
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .setContent("" + e.latlng.toString())
        .openOn(map);
}

map.on('click', onMapClick);

/* ----------------------------------------------- */
// MARKERS
//  var pkt = L.marker([54.46791, 17.0288]).addTo(map).bindPopup("CIO");
/* ----------------------------------------------- */

function addPoints(data, tabletop) {
    for (var row in data) {
        var marker = L.marker([
            data[row].Latitude,
            data[row].Longitude
        ]).addTo(map);
        marker.bindPopup('<strong>' + data[row].Info + '</strong>');
    }
}

function init() {
    Tabletop.init({
        key: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BTlWo-T636OCGK-tRMHRP55MQ24OwQ-ZF9yOszyppxk/edit?usp=sharing',
        callback: addPoints,
        simpleSheet: true
    })
}
init()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in JSFiddle doesn't work because the default JSFiddle javascript Load Type setting is `On Load`. This means that it will load everything that you have in JavaScript tab without you needing to load anything manually.

But your whole thing initializes with `onload` callback to `myFunction()` and it will never fire with that setting enabled. You have two possible solutions:

- if you don't want to change anything in Fiddle configuration, than you need to remove `onload` from the `body` tag and change `myFunction()` into self-invoking function:

  `(function () { **body of the function** }())`
- or just edit the Fiddle settings (change Load type to No wrap - Bottom of ):
  [image]

Comment: Ok. Thank You. For now I changed Fiddle settings but this is only a temporary solution, becouse I have it all in local hard drive and I fire this in default Chrome browser.

But after change settings it still didn't show points from gsheet file/link.

I can't force the code to show any view points in any kind of method to show the markers from the outside file (from csv, json or gsheet). I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I've made couple of changes to your Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a21yb4uq/
The main thing is that you need to load every outside script over ```https``` -  you were loading Tabletop script file over http and it can't be initialized in that way.

Comment: Thank you, I did not pay attention to this small thing. After recent changes on many pages, I need to look more closely at the inserted links. Thank you again for your help and your time.